# entity framework 5 codefirst with mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

can ef5 work with mysql when using code first approach?
when i'm trying to add new items to a not yet created table I'm getting "Table 'clients' doesn't exist.
if I'm switching to mssql everything works well.

this is my dbcontext

```
    public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public PowerToolsDBContext()
        : base("Name=MyContext") { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobData> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after adding database initializer

```
 static MyDBContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDBContext>());
    }
```